# Difference between `#cleanup` and `#teardown` in Test::Unit::TestCase

Tags: ruby, testing

Could anyone give me a good use case to illustrate the differences between Test::Unit::TestCase#cleanup and Test::Unit::TestCase#teardown?

Thx

Comment: Is this a legacy application? Otherwise you should be using `MiniTest::Unit::TestCase`. `Test::Unit` is dead.

Comment: it is legacy indeed. Thank you for pointing this out

Comment: @max, it doesn't seem to be legacy. It seems to be still being developed and better than minitest that appears stagnant and community unwilling to implement or even accept features.

Comment: @akostadinov do you have any sources for that claim?

Comment: @max, see https://github.com/test-unit/test-unit/, you can see that the project is active. I haven't seen any recent note that the framework is deprecated. Only obsolete references. Unfortunately it is not possible to edit outdated notes in the API. Can you show a recent post that the framework is obsolete?

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

- [`cleanup`](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/test-unit/test-unit/Test/Unit/TestCase#cleanup-instance_method) is called after every test method runs **but the test method isn't marked as 'passed'**.
- [`teardown`](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/test-unit/test-unit/Test/Unit/TestCase#teardown-instance_method) is called after every test method runs. (Regardless of whether or not the test passed.)

Comment: I had read this doc and unfortunately, I do not understand it.

Comment: What part do you not understand? If the test passes, then `cleanup` doesn't run; if the test fails, then `cleanup` does run. `teardown` **always** runs.

Comment: Thx for the clarification Tom. The way you rephrased it made much more sense to me ;-)